# Validate OSGi Manifest

Tags: java, osgi, manifest

What's the best way to parse and validate an OSGi manifest file? I've got a bunch of MANIFEST.MF files and there's a syntax error in one of them. What's the best tool to do this? I'd rather not have to load all the bundles into Eclipse to find the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like [BND](http://www.aqute.biz/Code/Bnd) tool can provide such manifest checking, but I'm not sure how ...

OK, According to the [command line](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/CommandLine) page, you can do a

```
 bnd print -verify *.jar
```

to check jar validity.

Besides, are your bundles not built in Eclipse world, I recommend you to create them using the excellent [Felix bundle plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) which is in fact a wrapper around the aforementionned BND.

Comment: Tried with `bnd` 3.5.0 and the verification flag should be `--verify` (two dashes).

Answer (score 1):

Spring also has manifest parsing and editing files in their libraries - the class is com.springsource.util.osgi.manifest.BundleManifest.